# Can we use a relational operator with list of values in JPQL + hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class interval {
       private Integer id;
       private LocalDateTime intervalDate;
}
```

I want to write a JPQL query to fetch all the intervals whose interval date is greater than a list of dates I pass to the query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT i from Interval i where i.intervalDate >= :listOfDates
```

where listOfDates is List<LocalDateTime> listOfDates = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I would suggest just find max(List<LocalDateTime> listOfDates) in java code and pass it to the query

Comment: further, I have criteria in which I will not be able to compare by extracting min/max.   
for example , i.startTime >= :startTimeList And i.endTime <= :endTimeList

Comment: What does 'interval date is greater than a list of dates ' mean? After the latest from the list? After all from the list? Or what? Or separately for each list item?

Comment: Do you mean an equivalent of the SQL `intervaldate >= ANY (...)` (or `SOME`) or `intervaldate >= ALL (...)`? JPQL does support `ANY`/`SOME` and `ALL`, but only with sub-queries, not with lists.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I wanted the SQL equivalent of `>=  ANY (...)` with a list.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a dedicated query per use case. Like suggested in the comments, one query with

```
SELECT i from Interval i where i.intervalDate >= :listOfDatesMax
```

where the `listOfDatesMax` parameter is set to the maximum from your list. And

```
SELECT i from Interval i where i.startTime >= :startTimeListMax And i.endTime <= :endTimeListMin
```

where again the `startTimeListMax` and `endTimeListMin` parameters are set to the maximum/minimum from the respective list.